# Help identifying composite decking

Tags: decking, composite

We purchased a home with composite decking. Some of it needs to be replaced. I've gone through the big box stores and dug around online, but can't figure out what it is we have. Hoping some wisdom here can help us narrow it down.

Does this look familiar to anyone?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like Timber Tech.

Comment: Thanks @HoneyDo, that's a pretty solid suggestion. I'm looking at their site and it does look like it could be it

Comment: If it does not pan out, try the local deck builders.  The deck might not have been done DIY.

Comment: Isn't that stuff supposed to last like forever? What's wrong that it needs some replacement?

Answer (score 1):

I installed Timber Tech on my deck so I'm pretty familiar with it. The grooves on the side are for their Concealoc fasteners that hold the decking onto the joists without screws through the decking.

Comment: Timbertech offers free samples, so I picked a couple that seem like a good shot at what we have. Thanks for the info on the fasteners as well, @HoneyDo. They did use them for the deck, but we'll need some for the work that we need to do, so that's really helpful.

Comment: The veranda line from HD is very similar and there are now "universal clips" for grooved deck boards - trex has a line of them.